# Node executing statements out of sequence within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using node-mysql to execute a query and return results.  Per standard mysql-node documentation, a callback function is executed once the query is complete passing an error object or result object.  Assuming the query executed correctly (and it does). I run through a for-in loop on the result and assign the fields in each row as one continuous message that I plan to send back to the calling so that it can be processed appropriately.  So, if a user wants to see the last 5 picks from a fantasy football draft, the function receives the num parameter (which is equal to 5) and then see a returned message showing details about all 5 picks transactions.  The function is as follows:

```
exports.getSelections = function(num){


 var query = "Select b.Player, b.Team, b.Position, a.Pick, c.Owner FROM Players b, Owners c,(Select * FROM Draft2 WHERE Year=2015 AND Player_ID >0 ORDER BY PICK DESC LIMIT " + num + ") a WHERE b.Player_ID = a.Player_ID AND c.Owner_ID = a.Owner_ID ORDER BY a.Pick DESC";


 var connection = mysql.createConnection(EXTERNAL_DATABASE_URL);
 connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields){
                    if(!err){
                        for( var i in results){
                            msg += "\n" + results[i].Pick + ". " + results[i].Owner + " selected " + results[i].Player + ",  " + results[i].Position + " from " + results[i].Team 
                        }

                    }else{
                        console.log(err);
                            msg = "There was an error processing your request";
                    }
                });      


                    connection.end(function(err){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("there was an error")
                        }else{
                            console.log("close connection");
                        }
                    });




                        console.log("message to be sent: " + msg);
                        return msg;         

};
```

The output through my console is always:

**message to be sent: undefined**

**this is what processed:** [shows the details of the sales transactions based on the number that was passed to the function and used in the query]

I see the results of the query in the second line above, as represented by [msg], so I know the query executed appropriately.

Here are my questions:

1. Can I get an explanation why the console would execute the **message to be sent** before finishing the actual loop.
2. If I want to ensure that the loop is complete before returning the value, how do I approach this?
3. Also, it appears that connection.end doesn't execute either. I presume I'm exiting the function too early??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What "loop" are you talking about? There's no loop in the code you posted. Database operations are **asynchronous**; that's why you pass callbacks to deal with the results.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code? There seem to be some indentation and probably scoping problems.

Comment: The loop that I'm referring to is the for(var i in results).

Comment: With the given code, if your query completes successfully but with an empty result set, `msg` will be undefined.

Comment: it doesn't have any empty result set.  The user can request the last 5, 10, etc records in a database table.  The num parameter is passed to the function and is used in the query.  I see the results when a number is passed but it looks like the code is evaluating the console.log("message to be sent: msg") before completing the for-in loop which is populating the msg variable.

Comment: You are not declaring your `msg` variable anywhere. Also, there is a missing closing `});` somewhere. Can you please fix your syntax error? It's important for us to know where the `connection.query(…` callback ends.

Comment: The "msg" variable is global - defined outside the scope of the function.  When I initiate the server, i declare it as a variable. I've also copied the complete function.  My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pointy hinted, the log is executing prior to the completion of the loop because the database operation `connection.query` is **asynchronous**. All of your operations are being executed in the correct sequence; its just that async operations resolve on their own timeline, which is why we have callbacks that run upon their completion.

You've already logged the value of `msg` before your `connection.query` callback even gets a chance to run.

Try moving your "message to be sent" `console.log` inside of the callback of the `connection.query` operation:

```
exports.getSelections = function(num) {
  var query = "Select b.Player, b.Team, b.Position, a.Pick, c.Owner FROM Players b, Owners c,(Select * FROM Draft2 WHERE Year=2015 AND Player_ID >0 ORDER BY PICK DESC LIMIT " + num + ") a WHERE b.Player_ID = a.Player_ID AND c.Owner_ID = a.Owner_ID ORDER BY a.Pick DESC";
  var connection = mysql.createConnection(EXTERNAL_DATABASE_URL);
  connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (!err) {
      for (var i in results) {
        msg += "\n" + results[i].Pick + ". " + results[i].Owner + " selected " + results[i].Player + ", " + results[i].Position + " from " + results[i].Team
      }
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      msg = "There was an error processing your request";
    }

    console.log("message to be sent: " + msg);

  });
  connection.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("there was an error")
    } else {
      console.log("close connection");
    }
  });

  return msg;
};
```

Also, might want to make sure `msg` is of type `String` before concatenating with `msg += "..."`

Comment: I did try that but wasn't having much luck. I did get it to work shortly after posting my updates to the code but I had to do it by creating a callback within the calling function and passing that as part of the parameters of the main function.  Should I be able to return the msg variable from within the main function I'm showing above?